# why my <mat-grid-list cols="2 >showing error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript, list

My angular project typescript showing this following problem:

```
error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
<mat-grid-list cols= "2" rowHeight= "200px">
```

my code is:

```
<div class="container"
            fxLayout="column"
            fxLayoutGap="10px">
            <div fxFlex>
                <div>
                    <h3>Menu</h3>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex>
                <mat-grid-list cols= "2" rowHeight= "200px">
                <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let dish of dishes">
                    <img height="200px" src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.name}}>
                    <mat-grid-tile-footer>
                        <h1>{{dish.name | uppercase}}</h1>
                    </mat-grid-tile-footer>
                </mat-grid-tile>
            </mat-grid-list>
            </div>
            <!-- <mat-list fxFlex>
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let dish of dishes">
                    <img matListAvatar src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.name}}>
                    <h1 matline>{{dish.name}}</h1>
                    <p matLine>
                        <span>{{dish.description}}</span>

                    </p>
                </mat-list-item>
            </mat-list> --> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have strict template binding enabled you need to use the correct types in the template.

In your case

`<mat-grid-list cols= "2" rowHeight= "200px">`

`rowHeight`is defined as string or number, so you are fine.
`cols` is defined as number, so you need to update you code as the follwoing:

`<mat-grid-list [cols]= "2" rowHeight= "200px">`

This interprets the 2 is it is, as a number.